# Where to store bearer token in ASP.NET Core 2.1 web client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, token

I'm writing a three level app. I have ASP.NET Core 2.1 Api, Web Client App and Android App. The Api is secured with Jwt Authorization. I have a problem in storing the token which I'm getting from the Api to Web Client. I need a secure way for that purpose and I'm thinking if it would be good way to store it in `ClaimsIdentity`. I'm going to add it here in:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, token.userId),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, token.userName),
    // Here add new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, token.token)
};

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

Is this the right and secure way?

Comment: Are you against the idea to use the Localstorage to store the bearer token?

Comment: I found something like Secret Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=macos but as Microsoft says it is only for dev purpose not production. So this is not good idea. Maybe I should use Cookie or Session variable?

Comment: ClaimTypes.Authentication is probably not the place - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.authentication?view=netframework-4.7.2). You could add your own custom claim like new Claim("access_token", token.token) - if you go down this approach make sure you set the httponly and secure flags. auth0 have some guidance [here](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found something that I can use.

https://hanssens.com/projects/localstorage

You can store lots of data in memory with this component. It also has encryption mode so it should be pretty secure. Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: HTML5 Web Storage is vulnerable to XSS, has a larger attack surface area, and can impact all application users on a successful attack. You can read this article, https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage  which talks about XSS & CSRF attacks.

Comment: Is this user specific? I have a .net core 2.0 client that gets a JWT token from a rest web service. I would like to have the token only used for my current user. Is there another way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I am used JwtBearer Authorization with ASP.NET Core 2.1 
for connect it with mobile ....

the token I stored in front end ... 
such as the mobile ... I stored it in setting file ... after open the app 
I check the value if exist or null

if exist ... make request using it
if Null ... request a new token

in web ... you can store it in local storage or cookies

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. In Android you can store it for example in database. But in a ASP it is not safe